# 503 Invalid sequence of commands (AUTH SSL/TLS required prior to authentication) through FTP proxy (Explicit mode)

Tags: linux, ssl, ftp

I'm trying to help a user connect to a remote ftp site with `lftp` version 4.7.8 on RHEL7 (I custom built `lftp` v4.7.8 for the user to be sure we're not running into a bug).

When we connect as the following, we keep getting an error:

```
mpenning@somewhere% ./lftp
lftp :~> set ftp:proxy "ftp://webgw.company.local:8021/"
lftp :~> set ftp:passive-mode on
lftp :~> set ftp:ssl-auth TLS
lftp :~> set ftp:ssl-force true
lftp :~> set ftp:ssl-allow true
lftp :~> set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
lftp :~> set ssl:verify-certificate no
lftp :~> set ssl:check-hostname false
lftp :~> set log:enabled true
lftp :~> open -u joe -p 21 ftps://some.thing.com
Password:
lftp joe@some.thing.com:~> ls
ls: Login failed: 503 Invalid sequence of commands (AUTH SSL/TLS required prior to 
authentication).
```

The proxy is a ProxySG (Bluecoat).

I have been beating this using various `lftp` options (plus re-compiling lftp) for a couple of hours.  What should we do to AUTH SSL/TLS (explicit, on port 21) as requested?

Comment: Try using steps listed [there](https://github.com/lavv17/lftp/issues/280). Also what port on `ftps://some.thing.com` are you connecting to? If it is 21, the connection will be Expicit FTP/S. If it is 990, it will be Implicit FTP/S. There could be different behavior in accessing them through proxy

Comment: It's indeed Explicit FTP/S, but the proxy doesn't seem to want to establish an SSL tunnel first. I can't figure out if there's something `lftp` can do to clue the Bluecoat in that this is explicit mode FTPS.

Comment: If you have access to ProxySG, you could configure it to accept FTPS over SOCKS. More is [there](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH244882.html)